# Key length not 128/192/256 bits, or Illegal key size when trying to initialize Bouncy Castle cipher in Java

Tags: java, cryptography, bouncycastle

I'm trying to encrypt a payload starting from a password using Bouncy Castle 1.58 (org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.58):

```
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEParameterSpec;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.Security;

public class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

        String password = "password";

        SecureRandom randomGenerator = new SecureRandom();
        byte[] salt = randomGenerator.generateSeed(256);
        PBEKeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt, 65536, 32);
        SecretKeyFactory f = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
        SecretKey passwordKey = f.generateSecret(keySpec);

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding", "BC");
        PBEParameterSpec parSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(salt, 65536);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, passwordKey, parSpec);
    }
}
```

and this is the error I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.util.BaseBlockCipher$InvalidKeyOrParametersException: Key length not 128/192/256 bits.
    at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.util.BaseBlockCipher.engineInit(Unknown Source)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1394)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1327)
    at tech.dashman.dashman.Scratch.main(Scratch.java:30)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Key length not 128/192/256 bits.
    at org.bouncycastle.crypto.engines.AESEngine.generateWorkingKey(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.crypto.engines.AESEngine.init(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.crypto.modes.GCMBlockCipher.init(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.util.BaseBlockCipher$AEADGenericBlockCipher.init(Unknown Source)
    ... 4 more
```

If I change the key length in the call to PBKeySpec to 256, like this:

```
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEParameterSpec;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.Security;

public class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

        String password = "password";

        SecureRandom randomGenerator = new SecureRandom();
        byte[] salt = randomGenerator.generateSeed(256);
        PBEKeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt, 65536, 256);
        SecretKeyFactory f = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
        SecretKey passwordKey = f.generateSecret(keySpec);

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding", "BC");
        PBEParameterSpec parSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(salt, 65536);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, passwordKey, parSpec);
    }
}
```

then I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.checkCryptoPerm(Cipher.java:1039)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1393)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1327)
    at tech.dashman.dashman.Scratch.main(Scratch.java:29)
```

What am I missing here? What size should be the key?

Comment: problem must be the `passwordKey`

Comment: @jen why? In what way?

Comment: can you please share a [mcve]

Comment: if i run your code i get: `java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: unknown parameter type.`

Comment: @Jens: there, the two examples with two different key sizes and two different errors. About your type error, not sure what's going on.

Comment: @Pablo Which bouncyCastle Version do youu use?

Comment: @Jens: 1.58 (updated the answer)

Comment: I alwas get the unknown Parameter type exceptioon, If i remove the `parSpec` it works fine for me

Comment: The keyLength argument in PBEKeySpec is in units of bits, *not* bytes. So the second example is the the correct one, and the error is explained by @wallenborn answer.

Comment: @JamesKPolk: yeah, I was specifying it in bytes to be through. Surprisingly, I'm still getting the other error after applying wallenborn's solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install the unlimited crypto extensions if you want to use AES with key sizes > 128 bit. The exception is actually telling you this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.checkCryptoPerm(Cipher.java:1039)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1393)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1327)
    at tech.dashman.dashman.Scratch.main(Scratch.java:29)
```

It's failing the check for Crypto Permissions on line 1039 of Cipher.java

Try setting the key length to 128 bit or install the Unlimited Key Strength policy which you can download [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html)

Comment: Oh! I knew and I forgot about the Unlimited Key Strength policy. Now that I added it, I stopped getting Illegal key size, but I'm still getting the other error. I'm going to accept this answer and create another question to keep things separate.